# Android: Always connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) on Reconnection

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, service

So, I start separate thread for using socket. And when user pressed home button I will close socket and interrupt thread all ok. But, after interrupt thread and after interrupted old thread user open my app I will begin start new thread immediately and doing connect socket I get following error:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /12.111.102.100 (port 3001): W/System.err(21440): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /12.111.102.100 (port 3001): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:825)
    at com.stm.classlife.services.SocketThread.run(SocketThread.java:47)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    ... 5 more

    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:825)
    at com.stm.classlife.services.SocketThread.run(SocketThread.java:47)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
    ... 5 more
```

I don't understand why I get connection error, anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can any one answer here me too facing similar issue..

Comment: I am also having same problem with a different context....can't seem to figure this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117522/cant-connect-to-wifi-network